# Cardinality of a quotient set of [0,1]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

Let $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define the equivalence relation

$$x \sim y \iff x-y = \frac{q}{2^k}$$

for some $q,k$.

How do I find the cardinalities of

1. the equivalence classes $[x]$
2. the quotient set $[0,1] \; /_\sim$

My guess is

1. $|[x]| = \aleph_0$ because the d’s are countable
2. $|[0,1] \; /_\sim| = \mathfrak{c}$ because $|[0,1]| = \mathfrak{c}$

but I don‘t see a rigorous proof.

Thanks

Comment: Wait.  Are $q$ and $k$ fixed?

Comment: no; it means that $x \sim y$ iff $\exists q \in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{N}:x - y= d(q,k)$.

Comment: Okay, so $[x]=\{y|x\sim y\} =\{y| x-y=\frac q{2^k}$ for some integer $q$ and some positive integer $k\} = \{x \pm \frac q{2^k}| q\in \mathbb Z; k\in \mathbb Z\}$.  So $[x]$ is countable.  And as $[0,1]$ is uncountable and $[0,1]=\cup_{[x]\in [0,1]/\sim} [x]$ that is a union of countable sets whose cardinality is uncountable.  As the union of *countably* many sets is countable this must be an *uncountable* union.  So $[0,1]$ must be uncountable.

Comment: thanks for clarification; that was my idea as well

Comment: Nonsense.  There are no d's mentioned in the problem.

Comment: original question improved; answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been clarified and answered by fleablood:

Let $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define the equivalence relation

$$x \sim y \iff \exists (q,k) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}: x-y = \frac{q}{2^k}$$

The cardinalities of

1. the equivalence classes $[x]$ and
2. the quotient set $[0,1] \; /_\sim$

are

1. $|[x]| = \aleph_0$ because $|\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$
2. $|[0,1] \; /_\sim| = \mathfrak{c}$ because $|[0,1]| = \mathfrak{c}$ **and** $[0,1]$ is the union of its equivalence classes, each of which is countable; if the quotient set itself would be countable, then $[0,1]$ would be countable as well; therefore the quotient set is uncountable.

$$[0,1] = \bigcup_{[x] \in [0,1]/_\sim} [x]$$